# using "with" statement on class methods

Tags: python

I'm required to use "with" on a method of an object and not on the object itself.

Here is what I've already tried:

```
class LSTM:
    ...

    def run(self):
        def __enter__(self):
            do something

            return self

        def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
            return self
```

An example of I want to use the function in main:

```
lstm = LSTM(...)
with lstm.run():
   ...
```

The error I get:

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: This is not how [context managers](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typecontextmanager.html) work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object *returned by your method* must be a context manager. Write your method as a generator and apply the [`contextlib.contextmanager` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to automatically create the proper helper object:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

class LSTM:
     @contextmanager
     def run(self):
         # prepare
         yield self
         # clean up
```

The object created by the decorator uses anything before the `yield` as `__enter__`, and anything after it as `__exit__`. Whatever is provided by `yield` is available for use in the `as` clause of the with statement. If an error terminates the context, it is raised at `yield`.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
with soemthing:
```

Then the object `soemthing` needs to have those `__enter__` & `__exit__` methods.

So for:

```
with lstm.run():
```

The object returned by `lstm.run()` needs to have the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods - the fact that `lstm` has those methods is of no consequence.

What you should do will depend on what you're trying to achieve. But this:

```
with lstm:
```

Will call the `__enter__` & `__exit__` methods you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

The context expression `lstm.run()` of your `with` statement does not evaluate to a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) but to `None`, since there is no `return` statement in your `run` method.

Cf. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement